# Multiple .click() events in Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I need to go to a website and get their data. I must make first click() to get to next option, on which i have to make another click() and then another click() and then another click().

I would like to make json from their database. You can check it here:

https://www.akumulator.pl/dobierz-akumulator

I already tried some tutorials on puppeteer and their official documentation

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async() => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
const models = [];
const fuels = [];
const engines = [];
const productions = [];

await page.goto('https://www.akumulator.pl/dobierz-akumulator');


const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let data = []; 
    let elements = document.getElementById('edit-brand').children;

    [].forEach.call(elements, element => {
        data.push(element.innerText);
    })
    return data; 
});

browser.close();
return result
}

scrape().then((value) => {
console.log(value); // Success!
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this in a loop:

```js
await Promise.all([
  page.$(selectorToClick).click(),
  page.waitForSelector(selectorToBeCreatedOrUnblocked)
]);
```